# php parse xml make result shuffle

Tags: php, shuffle

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item>
  <id>1</id>
  <num>10</num>
  <text>text1</text>
</item>
<item>
  <id>2</id>
  <num>8</num>
  <text>text2</text>
</item>
<item>
  <id>3</id>
  <num>17</num>
  <text>text3</text>
</item>
<item>
  <id>4</id>
  <num>5</num>
  <text>text4</text>
</item>
<item>
  <id>5</id>
  <num>9</num>
  <text>text5</text>
</item>
</items>
```

How to do  if `<num> >=9` , `shuffle` the items and print the `<text>`?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
foreach ($xml->item as $key=>$data){
    if(($data->num)>=9){
        ... 
    }
}
```

need out put like:

`text1  text3  text5` OR `text1  text5  text3` OR `text3  text1  text5` ... //text1  text3  text5 is not smaller than 9, then print them and make their position radom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When they pass, add them to an (associative) array.

After the foreach loop, `shuffle($array)` will shuffle them and then print them as usual (`echo $array[0].$array[1].$array[2]`).

Is this what you were looking for?

EDIT:

```
$passedArray = array();

$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
foreach ($xml->item as $key=>$data){
    if(($data->num)>=9){
        $passedArray[] = $data->text;
    }
}

shuffle($passedArray);
```

And then:

```
foreach ($passedArray as $value) {
    echo $value.' ';
}
```

This will leave a trailing space. This is better:

```
$string = '';

foreach ($passedArray as $value) {
    $string += $value.' ';
}

echo substr($string, 0, strlen($string)-1);
```

Comment: add `unset($array[$key]['text']);` in `foreach`?

Comment: After echo'ing all of it out? You COULD unset the array afterwards, but unless you're doing some things with unsanitized user-input, you don't really need to I think...

Comment: sorry, For I am newer, could u update a run code, for I still not echo what I need. Thanks.